# ValidationMessages stays cached until I restart the websphere application server

Tags: jsf, websphere, cdi, bean-validation, ibm-rad

My problem is that whenever I update or add any message in the ValidationMessages.properties, those messages won't reflected to the actual runtime validation message until restarting the application server (Just like the file being cached on the application server startup).

The only way to see the new changes is restarting the whole Websphere application server.

I tried to restart the application (EAR), republish it, clean and republish, change the "Publishing settings" on my IBM RAD, but none of them did the trick.

Noting that, I'm using the default implementation that's provided by IBM for JSF, CDI and Bean Validations.

I'm using IBM RAD 9.5.0.3 and Websphere 8.5.5.13 .

Comment: Where do you put the `ValidationMessages.properties` file?

Comment: They are under the src folder inside the war.
I tried to put them in a shared library and it did not do the trick (I thought it could be something related to the class loading policy so I tried to put it in a shared library with an isolated class loading policy).